# Recuperar los links de una página con botón ver más

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Estoy intentando obtener la información de las páginas de todos los enlaces de esta [web](https://www.recetasgratis.net). Estoy usando BeautifulSoup y Selenium. El problema que tengo es que no puedo obtener todos los enlaces de la página para después acceder a ellos y obtener la información de cada una de sus páginas.

Este es el código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url_meva = "https://www.recetasgratis.net"

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get(url_meva)

html = navegador.page_source
element_boto = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button")
element_boto.click()

last_height = 0
new_height = 1

while last_height < new_height:
    last_height = navegador.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("last height: ", last_height)
    navegador.execute_script("return document.body.scrollBy(0,1000)")
    new_height = navegador.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print("new height: ", new_height)
    total_receptes = navegador.execute_script('''
                var total = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link').length;
                return total;
                ''')
receptes = []
for item in range(total_receptes):


desc_item = navegador.execute_script(f'''
            var desc = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link')[{item}].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('alt');
            return desc;
            ''')

href_item = navegador.execute_script(f'''
        var href = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link')[{item}].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
        return href;
        ''')
 receptes.append([desc_item,href_item]) 

 print(total_receptes)
```

Lo que quiero hacer como primer paso es guardar todos los enlaces que aparecen en la página inicial para después abrirlos uno a uno y obtener la información de las páginas.

No me da ningún error. El problema es que en la página inicial no aparecen todos los enlaces. Hay que pulsar el botón Quiero ver más para que se vayan cargando los enlaces a medida que vas haciendo scroll. A pesar de hacer click en dicho botón no consigo ver todos los enlaces.

El problema es que no sé como hacer que la variable new_height tenga el nuevo valor después de hacer scroll. Para hacer scroll uso el comando javascript scrollBy(). Pero al asignarlo a new_height usando scrollHeight() no me lo asigna. Los valores de new_height y last_height acaban siendo iguales en la segunda iteración.

¿Como puedo arreglarlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno voy a intentar ayudarte, para empezar, no se hasta donde se llega haciendo `scroll` en esa página. Así que a modo de ejemplo, hice un simple `scroll` 5 veces cada 1seg. Puedes usar `Selenium` para ejecutar código `javascript` con `.execute_script`

```
url_meva = "https://www.recetasgratis.net"
browser.get(url_meva)
```

Click en el boton "Quiero ver más":

```
browser.execute_script('''
document.getElementsByClassName('boton l margin-bottom-3')[0].click();
''')
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_DOWN = 5
for _ in range(SCROLL_DOWN):

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height



#Obtener la cantidad de recetas
cantidad_recetas = browser.execute_script('''
                    var cantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link').length;
                    return cantidad;
                    ''')
recetas = []
for item in range(cantidad_recetas):


    desc_item = browser.execute_script(f'''
                var desc = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link')[{item}].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('alt');
                return desc;
                ''')

    href_item = browser.execute_script(f'''
            var href = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link')[{item}].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
            return href;
            ''')
    recetas.append([desc_item,href_item])
```

Bueno, lo que hago en el primer `for`, es hacer `scroll`. Si quieres bajar más, solo tienes que modificar la variable `SCROLL_DOWN`. Luego buscamos la cantidad de `items` que tiene la página y los agregamos a una lista. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

pd: a tu `navegador`, lo definí como `browser`

Y lo puedes guardar en un `excel` de esta manera:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(recetas)

df.to_excel('recetas.xlsx')
```

`.to_excel()` Recibe como parametro, el directorio donde deseas guardar tu `.xlsx`

**Actualización :**

Si quieres obtener todos los links de la página, solo tienes que hacer un loop similar al siguiente, donde sólo se romperá cuando ya no se pueda hacer `scroll`. De esta forma debería funcionarte :

```
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   #se puede agregar un sleep mas alto si no llega a cargar a tiempo.
    time.sleep(5)
    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Al darle un `KeyboardInterrupt` obtuve 13.000 recetas luego de varios minutos..

**Opción 2 :**

Otra solución que se me ocurre, puede ser usar `timedelta`, y hacer `scroll` un determinado tiempo que le pases por parametro, un ejemplo puede ser el siguiente:

En este caso hará `scroll` durante 35 minutos. Si quieres asignar más tiempo (por ejemplo una hora, debes pasarle por parametro "hour= X" siento X la cantidad de horas).

```
from datetime import timedelta 
import datetime

start =  datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes = 35)
while start >= datetime.datetime.now():

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

y luego obtener la cantidad de recetas:

```
#Obtener la cantidad de recetas
cantidad_recetas = browser.execute_script('''
                    var cantidad = document.getElementsByClassName('bloque link').length;
                    return cantidad;
                    ''')
recetas = []
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Lucas. Pero ahora tengo otro problema. Al poner tu código me sale un valor diferente cada vez que ejecuto el script. El valor más alto que me ha aparecido ha sido de 1639 enlaces con el valor de SCROLL_DWON = 5000. Otros valores han sido 57 con SCROLL_DOWN = 5 y 179 con SCROLL_DOWN = 50. Estoy muy lejos de los aproximadamente 25000 enlaces que debería ver. Es por esto que voy a retocar la pregunta con el nuevo código que he hecho explicando mi nuevo problema.

Comment: Ok. Estaré  atento  para editar la respuesta y ayudarte.